# Capture/filter text in Pandas df where every row has a unique starting point

Tags: python, pandas, string, filter, slice

I would like to search and show the IBAN number in a string. Only problem is that the starting position of the IBAN can vary. I tried the following but I only got NaN.

Btw if there are better ways to do so feel free to propose a different solution.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Description': ['some text IBAN xxxx', 'IBAN xxxx', 'some text some text IBAN xxxx']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Description'])
df['position'] = df['Description'].str.find('IBAN') 
df['IBAN'] = df['Description'].str.slice(start=df['position'], stop=8)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have IBAN from a single country, and the IBAN is always at the end of the string, you can try string slicing from the end. For example, for IBAN from Germany, which is 22 characters long, you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Description': ['some text IBAN xxxx', 'IBAN xxxx', 'some text some text IBAN xxxx']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Description'])
df['IBAN'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(" ", "")[-22:])
df
```

Using replace, you make sure that you consider IBAN with and without spaces.

Comment: That is sadly not the case in my original data file. The IBAN can start at the beginning, end or somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @Yavij are all IBAN from the same country?

Comment: Most of the IBAN are from the same country. It is, however, possible that the IBAN is from another country. That is an additional issue i need to solve.